# PHP script installation details storage

Tags: php, git, web

I am currently working on my first PHP project. It is a script that the users would be able to install on their web servers. The script requires database details and I can't find a secure way to save these settings. Should I write to a different file from `install.php`? I have checked and found that such methods could be prone to code injection, but nothing else is coming to mind at the moment.

Comment: Git is suitable for whatever project you are working on. It's even suitable for you even if you are not a developer and you want to version control your computer files! Git when designed was designed to be able to handle large project efficiently and fast, like Linux kernel. The guy created the kernel, Linus Torvalds, is the same guy created git :D

Check this introduction on git: https://learningpassion.wordpress.com/2016/06/15/git-tutorial-day-to-day-use-part-1-intro/

Comment: I know that Torvalds created both and I mostly use Linux, so I appreciate his work. Need for "Version Control" never got to me. I will need to check into the topic a bit further. My main question is however related to PHP. I need to create the script and make it functional before October starts.

Comment: It is best to ask just one question, asking two in one will stop you getting answers.

Comment: Removed the GIT question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration should be in a file not part of the distribution or ever added to version control.

Laravel, for example, provides a [`.env.example`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example) configuration file that has some suggested/example values, but installing Laravel creates a `.env` file from it.

WordPress does [a similar thing with `wp-config-sample.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-config-sample.php). You'd move it to `wp-config.php` and adjust the configuration values (although WordPress will, if server permissions are loose enough, do this for you).

Comment: Wordpress also provides web-based installation. Like when u start a new wordpress installation in the browser, the installation starts. I want to create something like that. Oxwall follows a very similar approach and later deletes the install folder.

Comment: @c0mmand0 I'm aware of that, which is why I stated "although WordPress will, if server permissions are loose enough, do this for you". In my opinion, this is totally unnecessary in most cases, especially now that most PHP projects are installed as Composer packages. WordPress's installer is open source, so if you want to see how it's done feel free to look.

Comment: Was hoping someone could simplify it. This is my first PHP project and therefore, I am not very comfortable with the advanced code thats on there.

Comment: @c0mmand0 It's fundamentally a simple HTML form that uses `fopen`/`fwrite` to create a `.php` file with the data the user put into the form. In my personal opinion, WordPress's approach is dangerous. The webserver should never be able to write the `.php` files (or really, anything outside a folder intended for processing uploads).

Comment: That is a popular approach though. So, I just allow it to write to a file and that's it?